# Jquery auto trigger click event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not able to trigger click event on the second td. When I try console

```
console.log($("#jq_quiz_task_container table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)").html());
```

The below result appears....

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="javascript:jq_QuizNextOn(); void(0);"  title="Next" onmouseover="jlms_WStatus('Next');return true;" onmouseout="jlms_WStatus('');return true;" class="btn btn-primary">&nbsp;Next&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
```

How do i trigger the click event for this 'a' inside second TD ?

I have tried the below code in the console

```
$("#jq_quiz_task_container table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) a").click();
```

But it displays the object in the console

```
[a.btn.btn-primary]
```

Please find the code as given below.

```
    <div id="jq_quiz_task_container" class="pull-right" style="float: right;">
        <table class="jlms_toolbar_buttons" align="right" style="text-align: right; width:auto; " cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">
                        <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="javascript:jq_QuizPrev(); void(0);" title="Prev" onmouseover="jlms_WStatus('Prev');return true;" onmouseout="jlms_WStatus('');return true;" class="btn btn-primary">&nbsp;Prev&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="middle" style="vertical-align:middle">
                        <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="javascript:jq_QuizNextOn(); void(0);" title="Next" onmouseover="jlms_WStatus('Next');return true;" onmouseout="jlms_WStatus('');return true;" class="btn btn-primary">&nbsp;Next&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us how are you trigger the event.

Comment: Have your tried `$("#jq_quiz_task_container table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) a").click();` ?

Comment: Panther I have updated the question... @NewToJS I tried it, but it displays object in the console.

Answer (score 0):

since we do not know what is the definition for jq_QuizNextOn(), it is hard to say what is going on.

If I define it as:

```
var jq_QuizNextOn = function(){
    console.log('test');
}
```

and then execute in console

```
$("#jq_quiz_task_container table tbody tr td:nth-child(2) a").click()
```

it will log "test" for me. tested in chrome.